# WildFly 8.2.0 (JBOSS) standalone server unable to start

Tags: java, jboss, startup, wildfly-8

I'm new to application servers. I downloaded the latest version of JBOSS (WildFly 8.2.0) and I wanted to start the standalone server as specified [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Getting+Started+Guide#GettingStartedGuide-StartingWildFly8).

I have properly set the JAVA_HOME (I use jdk 1.8.0_40) and JBOSS_HOME variables and also used the standalone.bat opposed to .sh file specified in the tutorial since I'm using windows(8.1).

However, when I execute the bat file the output is provided in the image below. It is clear that the server has not started and something has gone wrong. I checked the localhost which returned page not found.
[image: Output of server startup]

How to fix this issue so I could run the standalone JBOSS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar situation a few days ago. If you go inside your bin folder to locate the standalone.bat and open in a text editor. On lines 167-168, you will see something similar to the following:

`echo Setting JAVA property to "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"
set "JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"`

Try deleting the "\bin" so that `set "JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java` becomes `set "JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\java`.

Lastly, I highly recommend checking your `JAVA_HOME` variable in your `PATH` again to make sure it's set to the correct path.

Hope that solves your problem!

Comment: if this resolves the problem, JAVA_HOME should be fixed.